# Python socket server - Not receiving Adobe AIR client data on Windows

Tags: python, sockets, air, platform

I have setup a socketserver in Python (my first program in Python) using the following code:

```
class setupServer(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, host, port):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

def now(self):
    d = datetime.datetime.now()
    return d.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")

def run(self):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((self.host, self.port))
    server.setblocking(0)
    server.listen(3)
    inputs = [server]
    print("Server started!")

    while inputs:
        readable, writeable, error = select.select(inputs,[],[])
        for s in readable:
            if s is server:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                print('contact', addr, 'on', self.now())
                conn.setblocking(0)
                inputs.append(conn)
            else:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    print("Received msg: ", data.decode())
                else:
                    print('close')
                    inputs.remove(s)
                    s.close()
```

(Please note that I'm not finished with handling the received data besides printing it and errors)

Clients are connecting using an AIR socket. On Unix-based systems everything seems to work fine. I've tested sending data from my Android phone and from an OSX system.

On Windows clients however I can connect, but I'm only receiving something the instant after AIR connected to the server (it sends a testmessage).
Everything sent afterwards does not reach the socket server.

I also tried using the socket.settimeout functionality, but that gives the exact same problem. Changing AIR to Flash, and different versions does not make a difference either. But taken the fact that everything works on OSX and Android, I would assume the problem lies with Windows.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?
(I'm using Windows 8 on the AIR client PC's. I can also post the AIR code if required, but it is extremely basic, sending messages using writeUTFBytes())